# Updating screen to render camera position

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have converted C++ source from using GLUT to using SDL/OpenGL The problem is since I have changed from GLUT the 'camera's position is not getting updated, so rather than moving around using the keyboard, the screen just sits there renders what it needs and does not update.

The keyboard strokes are working as I have set it up so when ESC is pressed it exits and this is fine.

Here is my Display function this gets called every loop and also upon keypress(wasd):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
Camera.Render();
glTranslatef(0.0,-0.5,-6.0);

....Draw some stuff....

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
```

next up the Camera.Render();

```
SF3dVector ViewPoint = Position+ViewDir;
gluLookAt(Position.x,Position.y,Position.z,ViewPoint.x,ViewPoint.y,ViewPoint.z,UpVector.x,UpVector.y,UpVector.z);
```

Now what happens once a key is pressed(w which should move the camera forward):

```
case SDLK_w:
    CCamera().MoveForward( -0.1 ) ;
    Display();
    break;
```

and finally CCamera().MoveForward() function:

```
MoveForward(GLfloat Distance){
    Position = Position + (ViewDir*-Distance);
}
```

I cant for the life of me work out why once a key is pressed it doesnt update the position.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCamera()` just creates a temporary camera. (Which you then move.) Then the temporary goes away.

Perhaps you meant to modify `Camera`?

Comment: You my friend are a master! no wonder your name is GMan. Thanks a lot. my question seems like a silly one now.

Comment: @Elgoog: It's okay, everyone does it at least once.